# Concurrent server using pthread API

Tags: c++, pthreads, client-server

I am writing a simple client-server application using pthread-s API, which in pseudo code
looks something like this:

```
static volatile sig_atomic_t g_running = 1;
static volatile sig_atomic_t g_threads = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t g_threads_mutex;

static void signalHandler(int signal)
{
  g_running = 0;
}

static void *threadServe(void *params)
{
  /* Increment the number of currently running threads. */
  pthread_mutex_lock(&g_threads_mutex);
  g_threads++;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_threads_mutex);

  /* handle client's request */

  /* decrement the number of running threads */
  pthread_mutex_lock(&g_threads_mutex);
  g_threads--;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_threads_mutex);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   /* do all the initialisation 
      (set up signal handlers, listening socket, ... ) */

   /* run the server loop */
   while (g_running)
   {
     int comm_sock = accept(listen_socket, NULL, 0);
     pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &threadServe, comm_sock) ;
     pthread_detach(thread_id);
   }

   /* wait for all threads that are yet busy processing client requests */
   while (1)
   {
     std::cerr << "Waiting for all threads to finish" << std::endl;;

     pthread_mutex_lock(&g_threads_mutex);
     if (g_threads <= 0)
     {
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_threads_mutex);
       break;
     }
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_threads_mutex);
   }

   /* clean up */
}
```

So the server is running in an infinite loop until a signal (SIGINT or SIGTERM) is received. The purpose of the second while loop is to let all the threads (that were processing client requests at the time a signal was received) to have a chance to finish the work they already started.
However I don't like this design very much, because that second while loop is basically a busy loop wasting cpu resources.

I tried to search on Google for some good examples on threaded concurrent server, but I had no luck. An idea that came to my mind was to use `pthread_cond_wait()` istead of that loop, but I am not sure if this does not bring further problems.

So the question is, how to improve my design, or point me to a nice simple example that deals with similar problem as mine.

EDIT:

I was considering `pthread_join()`, but I din't know how to join with worker thread,
while the main server loop (with `accept()` call in it) would be still running.
If I called `pthread_join()` somewhere after `pthread_create()`
(instead of `pthread_detach()`), then the while loop would be blocked until the worker
thread is done and the whole threading would not make sense.
I could use `pthread_join()` if I spawned all the threads at program start,
but then I would have them around for the entire life of my server,
which I thought might be a little inefficient.
Also after reading man page I understood, that `pthread_detach()` is exactly
suitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The busy loop slurping CPU can easily be altered by having a `usleep(10000);` or something like that outside your mutex lock.

It would be more light-weight if you use a `std::atomic<int> g_threads;` - that way, you could get rid of the mutex altogether.

If you have an array of (active) thread_id's, you could just use a loop of

```
for(i = 0; i < num_active_threads; i++) 
   pthread_join(arr[i]);
```

Comment: In-depth discussion about the equivalent of WaitForMultipleObjects for Posix over on the Apple forums:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/mt-smp/2007/Aug/msg00016.html

Wiki-article on readers-writers problem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my question to explain, why I have used pthread_detach()
instead of pthread_join(). Sofar it seems, that I will follow your first suggestion,
with usleep(), but I still want to keep this question open for a little while,
before accepting your answer ...
Also would do you think about my idea, with pthread_cond_wait() ?
Can it be used this way ?

Comment: My point of `pthread_join()` is only to wait for the threads once you have decided to stop accepting new connections. At that point, you don't need to worry about calling `accept`, and I don't see anywhere saying that `pthread_detach` and `pthread_join` are not possible to us together. I'm not sure how you would use `pthread_cont_wait` in a meaningful way here. The only way I see it useful is if you also add more complex logic to the thread itself, which I don't see the point of.

Comment: Actually I am quite new to pthread-s and threading in general so I thought, I could
use `pthread_cond_wait()` for some kind of signalling that the worker thread is done
with its job. But never mind, that would most likely, as you say it also, be too
complex to be worth it.

Comment: And about mixing `pthread_detach()` and `pthread_join()` man page for `pthread_detach()`
states this: "Once a thread has been detached, it can't be joined with pthread_join(3)
 or be made joinable again.", so that is why I assumed that I either use `pthread_join()`
or `pthread_detach()` to clean the thread up.

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that part about not being joinable again. Sorry about that. The problem with `pthread_cond_wait` is that you need to have know when to signal it - your threads essentially need to know if you are quitting and if there are no threads left - which means you move most of your logic of your second wait loop to the serve_thread, which makes that more complex, and not really helping you solve the problem - and if there are NO threads, your waiting loop will still need to know that and not wait - because no thread can "wake it".

Comment: Ok, so that clears it up, thanks for your responses and time. I will stick with
your initial suggestion, with usleep(). Anyways few minutes of almost busy waiting
at the end of program won't kill anyone ...

Comment: Well, if you are expecting (literaly) minutes, I'd use a longer sleep time - 1 second or so would work.